# UIView Animation of MPMoviePlayerController view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a movie playing successfully in a container view that is managed by

```
BWCVideoViewController : UIViewController
```

When I start the movie (which works fine), I fade the movie view in successfully using the following

```
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
theMovie.view.alpha = 0.0;
[theMovie play];
[self movieFadeIn];


- (void)movieFadeIn
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         theMovie.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }
                    completion:nil];
```

}

But for the life of me I cannot fade the movie view out when the movie is either stopped or still playing!  It just "flashes" and disappears abruptly:

```
- (void)movieFadeOut
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         theMovie.view.alpha = 0.1f;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

I've followed suggestions elsewhere on SO such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984478/fading-out-mpmovieplayercontroller-controls) but I'm baffled.  Same result in simulator/device (iOS7)

Comment: have you tried to change the value of your delay? 
and you try inversing the order like this:
theMovie.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
[theMovie play];
[self movieFadeIn];

Answer (score 0):

Well I've solved it, but not how I expected to.
I created another subview (so it sits ABOVE the video) with the same frame size.  I fade this out/in and get the desired result.  weird.